# For Each Element in Two Lists

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, foreach

This is my code:

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "x", "y", "z" };
foreach (var item in l1)
{
    item = MyFunction(item);
}
foreach (var item in l1)
{
    item = MyFunction(item);
}
```

Is there a way to iterate both the Lists in a single foreach statement ?

Comment: I assume you meant to iterate `l2` in the second foreach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the type of the `List` objects are the same you can use `Concat`.

```
foreach (var item in l1.Concat(l2))
{
    item = MyFunction(item);
}
```

Comment: No braces needed for this sample code; one-liner loop body. Of course it functions exactly the same and the OP had them, so...

Comment: @KeithS 1) I see no reason to remove them.  If the OP wants them there, then that's fine.  2) The fact that he's assigning a value to `item` implies he's going to use it, which means there are likely more lines of code not shown here (which also explains the motivation for combining the two `foreach` loops). 3) Many people prefer to use braces in such contexts even when there is only one statement; it's a personal preference issue.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Concat() function:

```
foreach(var item in l1.Concat(l2))
   item = MyFunction(item);
```

Be aware that reassigning the counter variable of an Enumerable-based loop can cause exceptions relating to changing the underlying IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var mergedList = 11.Union(l2).ToList();
foreach (var item in mergedList)
{
    item = MyFunction(item);
}
```

The Union removes any duplicates. The Concat() method does not. So Union might be preferrable. It depends on the composition of the lists.

Comment: Note that `Union` will remove duplicates, and so wouldn't be functionally equivalent to the code in the OP.